# Image request aborted

Tags: javascript, image, apache, http

My application requires users to peruse through certain images using jquery/AJAX. It works fine on local however in production server some requests get aborted. Here is a snapshot of the same. I can't figure out why this is happening to certain images. (the URL are fine and the images are actually present)

I get the image name through the ajax request and then change the src of the image element on the page to display the image.

[image]

Comment: Firefox will "abort" some Ajax requests if they take too long to arrive. JQuery has a "timeout" setting you can use with your Ajax request docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). I haven't found much else specific to Firefox, but here are some similar symptoms in IE: http://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/01/28/what-does-aborted-mean-in-httpwatch/.

Comment: This is what I figured out. The problem occurs when the user requests a change of image way too quickly(kind of like trying to go really fast through facebook image gallery).

Comment: Nice. If Firefox determines it no longer needs the image before it has finished downloading it may also cancel the request. You can probably just ignore those rows, then.